# Which scripture is the source of Naama-Aparaadha?

Tags: puranas, identification-request, sin

According to Srimad-Bhagavatam, chanting of Hari-Naama destroys all sins in the age of Kali.

But, the Gaudiya Vaishnava Literature states that no result of Hari-Naama is obtained if one incurs 'Naama-Aparaadha'.

This list of such Aparaadhas mentioned is so delicate that it is impossible for a common man to do Naama without Naama-Aparadha.

Which scripture first mentions these Naama-Aparaadhas?

Comment: Since Aparadha means offence/sin you can add the sin tag and i think its also related to Vaishnavism as well .. so that tag can be added too.. btw what is nama aparadha?

Comment: @Rickross a long list that says that nama will not work for example if one has slightest disbelief.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is from Padma Purana, Brahma Khanda, 25th Chapter, verses 15-20.

Sanatakumara speaks:(4.25.15-20)

> The censure of the good causes a great sin against the name (of
>   Visnu). How does (i.e. would) it tolerate the censure of those on
>   account of whom it has become famous? He indeed does ill to the name
>   of Visnu, who, in this world, would regard all (things) about the
>   auspicious Sri Visnu, as different from his own mind. He who does not
>   disrespect his preceptor, who does not censure sacred texts, who does
>   not look upon Visnu's name as (merely) glorificatory, who does not
>   have a wicked idea about (i.e. to look upon) name (as) sinful, has
>   purification by means of restraints. Indifference to religious vows,
>   sacrifice (for others), offering oblations, all good actions is also a
>   fault. Not having faith, turning away one's face, not listening to
>   advice is also a sin against the auspicious name. He, the mean man,
>   who, even after hearing the greatness of (Visnu's) name, remains
>   without love for it, and is only intent upon 'I', 'mine' etc. (i.e. is
>   selfish), has committed sin against the name (of Visnu). O Narada,
>   Siva, with grace, told the sages and me the great name of the lord,
>   bringing happiness. It should always be carefully preserved. They who
>   even knowing (the importance of name), do not suddenly avoid the ten
>   sins against the name, are like children, who being angry, afflict
>   their mother. Being free from sins, always mutter the name (of Visnu).
>   O divine sage, due to name only you will accomplish everything and not
>   by any other means.

You can read whole chapter [here](https://archive.org/details/PadmaPuranaMotilalVol.3Thru10/page/n757)

Comment: "He indeed does ill to the name of Visnu, who, in this world, would regard all (things) about the auspicious Sri Visnu, as different from his own mind." This is confusing @KrishnaVarna, All things auspicious about visnu should be deemed fabrication of his own mind is it.. this seems to me some advaita commentary.. Please confirm

Comment: @PrasannaR Refer alternate translation here.. https://iskcondesiretree.com/page/the-ten-offenses-to-the-holy

Comment: @KrishnaVarna The translation you provided in the answer seems to connote few things totally different from the link you provided to PrasannaR. I hope MLBD translation is close to the original.

Comment: @Pratimaputra I think mlbd translation is little far or unclear from original meaning... It is about words sivasya, bhinna or abhinna word chosen as per sandhi that causes the difference. The link I provided to Prasanna R closely follows Jiva Goswami commentary in Bhakti Sandarbha..

Comment: @KrishnaVarna How that could be? Sri Jiva never used even the concepts like demigod.

Comment: @Pratimaputra see here for 2nd offense https://www.jiva.org/spiritual-names-and-their-powers/

Comment: It has original Sanskrit. @Pratimaputra

Comment: @KrishnaVarna oh thanks got it.Thnx.No concept like demigods as I expected:)