# What is the correct meaning of 10 namapradhas in Padma Puran?

Tags: padma-purana, nama

Can somebody translate or tell the correct meaning of the Ten namapradhas mentioned in Padma Puran

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which scripture is the source of Naama-Aparaadha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33556/which-scripture-is-the-source-of-naama-aparaadha)

Comment: No,Thank you very much.